# Images not displaying after upload to server

Tags: html, image, ftp, server

I uploaded website to my server using ftp on Mac's terminal.

None of my images are being displayed on my site.

There is an images directory inside www directory

12-01-15  11:49AM                 www

12-01-15  10:04AM                 images

My image is located inside the images directory within www

Here is my path on html page at the moment...

```
<img src='\www\images\choclogo.jpg'>
```

I've changed the path at least 20 times but no luck. I've also changed image type, png jpg etc.

Comment: Can you view the images when you open them directly in your browser? e.g. www.yourwebsite.org/images/choclogo,jpg ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to prepend `www`? Modern configurations of apache have a `www/html` folder, even then, the path to your image is just `images/choclogo.jpg`

And, you should use `/` slashes instead of `\`, because it's not Windows, it's the web ;) Try `www/images/choclogo.jpg` or else `images/choclogo.jpg`

Comment: Still no luck. Thank you though.

Comment: Are you sure the images are being uploaded? What does a `ls` command inside the directory `images` show?

Comment: I would advise you to use a FTP client with a user interface, this should clear things up. I like Cyberduck (https://cyberduck.io)

Comment: ls inside images directory shows choclogo.jpg...I download cyberduck and see

Comment: Are you using apache? Try creating a `html` folder inside the `www` folder, and putting the `images` folder in there, then use `images/choclogo.jpg ` to try and access it.

Answer (score 0):

Using FileZilla, I changed the `Default transfer type` in `Settings > Transfers > File Types` to `Auto`. That solved my problem.